# Laravel policies - passing the class as a variable to $user->can() method doesn't work

Tags: laravel

I have a route with dynamic model recognition. In other words, I take the desired model as an argument and use it in the controller. I have complex authorization in my app and I need to pass the model class name as a variable to the $user->can() method for using policies, but for some reason it doesn't work. Here's my code:

Policy:

```
public function view($user, Model $model) {
     return $user->model_id == $model_id;
}


public function create($user) {
     return $user->isAdmin();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function createModel($model) {
     $model_class = $model . '::class';
     if (Auth::user()->can('create', $model_class)) {
           return $model_class::create();
     }
     return 'invalid_permissions';
}
```

If I hardcode the model class name it works. For example, if my model is 'Car' and in the controller I put:

```
if (Auth::user()->can('create', Car::class)) {
```

Anybody got any ideas why this is so and how to fix it? I hope that it's possible because I would have to change my whole concept if it isn't. 

*Note: this is example code, not my actuall classes

Comment: Does it produce an error, or just create a model when it should?

Comment: @jackel414 It doesn't produce an error, it just returns false (i.e. doesn't authorize) and I am absolutely certain that the user has authorization for the action.

Comment: Are you using 'Car' in your dynamic example, and is the Policy code above from your CarPolicy? If so, did you 'dd' in the create method to confirm that the code is actually accessing that method?

Comment: @jackel414 Yes, I am using car in the dynamic example, and yes, I am certain that it's the right policy, and I did dd (I used var_dump though) in the create method, it doesn't access it. When I make it static, write 'Car::class' as the second argument to the policy instead of passing it as a variable, it works and authorizes properly

Comment: Line 2 what is $model_id?

Comment: @ChristopherRaymond it just checks if the authenticated user owns the current model. It's just an example and that's not the problem, policies that require a model work well, I'm having problems with dynamically passing the class name to policies that don't require an instance, such being the create policy

Comment: Understood. I think you're trying to pass a string

Comment: @ChristopherRaymond That's right, I'm trying to pass the class name as a string. I don't know why it doesn't work in this case as I'm using that technique a lot without any problems of this sort, or any sort for that matter

Comment: I don't have the setup to test this right now, but I'd try registering (and then calling) the class/policy in this format in your AuthServiceProvider: `'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy'`. I know either work in Laravel, but since that format is using a string, it might be more friendly to the way in which you're trying to use it.

Comment: What about this --> if (Auth::user()->can('create', $model::class))

Comment: @jackel414 I actually already have it in that format, not the other one, I just checked
ChristopherRaymond I tried that before, it throws an error. This is the error:
Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch
*Note: when I pass in the whole class name (e.g. 'Car::class') as a whole string it doesn't throw an error

Comment: "{$model}::class"

Comment: @ChristopherRaymond That didn't work. However, I just tried passing it a string that contains only 'App\Car' without '::class' and without the first backslash and it worked. I can't find an explanation as to why that's so, but at least it worked. Thanks for the help guys :)